# For how long I legally have to support my marketing email unsub link

Tags: email, unsubscribe

I want to change the unsub link inside my marketing mail. When I will change it, all the old unsub link inside the email sent before will not work anymore.

So if a client wants to unsub from the marketing mail with an old sent email, he will not be able to unsub and need to receive an other marketing mail before he can.

Do I have to legally keep the link working for ever or I have a date range, example: 6 months ??

Thanks

Comment: This is 100% subjective. Six months seems reasonable The longer the better. Keep in mind that people usually unsubscribe when they read something they no longer want, they don't dig through multi-year old archives the same way. If you sent them one email five years ago, nobody cares. If you're bugging them *today* they do.